# Does a simple delphi form app needs any libraries or dependencies to deploy?

Tags: delphi, reference, dependencies, delphi-2010, libraries

I need to code a simple form application and I want to make it easy to deploy (without installing libraries or dependencies), I don't want to use visual studio cpp or csharp because clr apps compile with .net frameworks and I have no much experience with mfc and dialogs.

So I was wondering which libraries does a simple delphi vcl forms app (those using TForm) use, because I've never had to install anything to run simple delphi apps.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Delphi embeds everything in the EXE file.   There are libraries that depend on BPL or DLL files, but for a simple application, the EXE is all you need...

Comment: One could build the application so that it requires BPL files, but it's rarely done.  The components that rely on external DLLs normally indicate as such in their documentation.

Comment: Sparky is right. The default in Delphi is everything in one .exe, even though there are other ways (BPLs mostly). The base GUI components do not depend on DLLs.

Comment: Thank you all, I didn't know everything was embedded in the exe.

Comment: Many delphi developers love this about delphi, and point the "runtime dll and framework installation" requirements of almost-every-other-tool as a key reason why they prefer delphi.